# Codeigniter redirect to empty form

Tags: forms, codeigniter, view

I have the follow form in Codeigniter:

The controller:

```
    public function item($alias = NULL){
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $data['title'] = 'Edit menu';
    $data['menu_item'] = $this->menu_model->get_menu($alias);
    $data['articole'] = $this->menu_model->get_articole();
    $data['menuactive'] = $this->menu_model->get_menuactiv();
    $data['errors'] = $this->form_validation->error_array();
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('position','Position','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('position','Position','numeric');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name','Name','required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
        $data['name'] = $data['menu_item']['name'];
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/youarehere', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/menu', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/admin', $data);
        $this->load->view('menu/item', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
    else {
        $this->menu_model->update_menu();
        redirect('menu');
    }
}
```

The item view is:

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<?php echo form_open('menu/item'); ?>

<?php echo form_label('ID ', 'id'); ?>
<?php echo form_input('id', $menu_item['id'], 'readonly'); ?><br><br>

<?php echo form_label('Name ', 'name'); ?>
<?php echo form_input('name', $menu_item['name']); ?><br><br>

<?php echo form_label('Position ', 'position'); ?>
<?php echo form_input('position', $menu_item['position']); ?><br><br>

<?php foreach($articole as $articole_item):

    $articol1[] = $articole_item['id'] . ' ' . $articole_item['title'];

endforeach; ?>

<?php echo form_label('Associated article ', 'associated_article'); ?>
<?php echo form_dropdown('associated_article', $articol1, $menu_item['articol_asociat']); ?><br><br>

<?php echo form_label('Menu activ ', 'activ'); ?>
<?php echo form_checkbox('activ', '1', TRUE); ?><br><br>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save menu"/>
</form>
```

In this view I edited menu items. Everything works fine when when everything is right. When I introduce something wrong in a field, like string into "position" field, the form redirect to item view, but with empty fields and with the error message. I want to keep what is entered in field and the error message.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: I'd start by having a look at the data from this `$data['menu_item'] = $this->menu_model->get_menu($alias);`. Do a `var_dump( $data['menu_item'] );die;` on the line below and see if the data is in there.

Comment: Yes, there are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your form :

```
<?php echo form_label('ID ', 'id'); ?>
<?php echo form_input('id', set_value('id'), 'readonly'); ?><br><br>

<?php echo form_label('Name ', 'name'); ?>
<?php echo form_input('name', set_value('name')); ?><br><br>

<?php echo form_label('Position ', 'position'); ?>
<?php echo form_input('position', set_value('position')); ?>
```

set_value() replace your old values